# RDP locally with Broker Load Balancer enabled

Tags: windows, rdp, terminal-services

This isa configuration of Remote Services for serving remote apps in windows 2016 server via rdp:

```
host1 - Session Host - Collection1 - notepad
host2 - Session Host - Collection1 - notepad
broker1 - Broker + Web Server
```

If I connect from an external client via rdp I can execute notepad remotely on the less loaded host, thats correct as I have the load balancer equally for both hosts. The flow is to go to the broker, and the broker will redirect you to the hostN. I can retrieve the rdp file from remote web server.

What I cant do is to, inside host1 and for new sessions, connect via rdp locally to run an app on that host. It always goes to the broker to decide where to go. Even if I specify full address as localhost it can go to host1 or host2, it is not deterministic.

Is there any option to specify remote app host and skip broker Load Balancing?

Many thanks.

Comment: As specified https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/c4de4069-19b2-4af8-8751-97f8d9677b4f/accessing-rds-host-servers-via-rdp-that-are-behind-a-connection-broker?forum=winserverTS you can use `mstsc.exe \admin`  but this only works if the user accessing has admin rights. I am looking for a non-admin privilege way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

you can disable the GPO setting Use RD Connection Broker load balancing which is under Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\RD Connection Broker. Make sure that the GPO is linked to the OU of your RD Session Host servers.